# Average n rows for each part and then last n rows for the same part

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a csv file which has about 10 rows of output values along with temperature measurements for each part. There are about 100 parts. But I want the following:

Average only first 3 rows for each part, display part, average value, avg temp
Average last 3 rows for that same part, display part, average value, avg temp

```
Row#|PartID|Output|Temp(C)
--------------------
  1 |  435 | 70 | 25
  2 |  435 | 30 | 21
  3 |  435 | 20 | 20
  ..|  ... | ...| ...
  8 |  435 | 50 | 10
  9 |  435 | 35 | 15
 10 |  435 | 45 | 20
 11 |  525 | 60 | 25
 12 |  525 | 15 | 20

and so on

mydata <- csv.read("some file.csv", header=T)
# maximum number of rows to evaluate
nmax <- 3
n <- 1
for i in unique(part, margin=1) 
{
  while (n<nmax)
     {
       apply(mydata, 2, mean)
       n = n+1
     }
}
```

Basically, my result for first part ID should be:

```
First Output (Average first 3 rows):

PartID|Output|Temp
 435  |  40  | 23

Second Output (Average last 3 rows):

PartID|Output|Temp
 435  |  43.3| 15
```

I have only shown code which evaluate average of first 3 rows. Am I going in right direction? Any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` one way is to select first 3 and last 3 rows for each `PartID`, create an additional group of every 3 rows and take `mean` of the columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(PartID) %>%
  slice(c(1:3, (n()-2):n())) %>%
  group_by(group = rep(c(1, 2),each = 3)) %>%
  #Or group_by(group = gl(n()/3, 3)) %>%
  summarise_all(mean) %>%
  select(-Row, -group)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  PartID Output Temp.C.
#   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#1    435   40        22
#2    435   43.3      15
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Row = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 10L), PartID = c(435L, 
435L, 435L, 435L, 435L, 435L, 435L), Output = c(70L, 30L, 20L, 
20L, 50L, 35L, 45L), Temp.C. = c(25L, 21L, 20L, 20L, 10L, 15L, 
20L)), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Error in df %>% group_by(PartID) %>% slice(c(1:3, (n() - 2):n())) %>% group_by(group = rep(c(1,  : 
  could not find function "%>%"

Comment: @SalN85 you need to install `dplyr` package for this, do `install.packages("dplyr")`, then `library(dplyr)` and run the above code.

Comment: `n()` gives total number of rows in the group, so by doing `(n()-2):n())` we are selecting last 3 rows in each  `PartID`.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is helpful. So if I have 7000 rows for example, then it would be slice(c(1:1000, (n()-6000):n())) if I choose first 1000 and last 1000 rows

Comment: first part is correct, for last 1000 rows you'll need to do `c(1:1000, (n() - 999) : n())`. Since `n() -999` would give you 6001 and create a sequence from there till `n()` which is 7000.

Comment: This code displays for one part id. What if I want to display multiple parts with average value?

Comment: @SalN85 this would still work for multiple `PartID`. Did you run the code? `group_by(PartID)` takes care of this.

Comment: Yeah, it only shows one table. It averages part id as well. No worries, I will figure it out.

Comment: yes, but since we are grouping by `PartID` it would give the same `PartID` for each group. Also if you want to split it into different dataframes you can add `%>%
  group_split(row_number(), keep = FALSE)` to the current code.